How to get all all user profil from AAD using power automate including properties
Iwouldlike to have a routine that dumps user profiles out to a csv/excel and also sync to a SharePoint list.What are my options with Power automate.
I'm looking at the 2 connectors below
1)Search for user(v2)
2)Send an HTTP request V2
FYI I don't have a premium license for PA and don't want to use powershell
Any other options or tips would be appreciated

You can get all Entra ID (formerly Active Directory) users from group where all users are added. In my experience, every company have such group already and it is up to date with all active & real user accounts. Then iterate through it and do your stuff! :)
Action of interest: Microsoft Entra ID "GetGroupMembers"
Admins rights not needed and is in free-to-use tier.


Thanks Kristaps Vilerts. Great  dea and will see if I have such a geoup to use

Thanks Kristaps for the solution but I can't get to retrieve all properties. Is this possible?

I have decided to use graph api (Send http request V2- Office 365) for this where i can query any properties I want
